# pear mail script failed to open stream error

Tags: php, email, pear

I am using pear mail to send emails. I have configured the mailer to my gmail SMTP & on a test script everything is working fine. However after I integrated the same script to my actual project I get the following error. Been trying for hours still can't find any clue to the problem.

> Warning: require(libs/LOGIN.php) [function.require]: failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   E:\WAMPServer\www\myProject_Updated\index.php

Comment: include pear to include path or check the folder in the error message

Comment: path issue.check your path

Answer (score 0):

You want to set up email server , without email server you can not send email in your local PC.

Please visit to this site , you can find how to setup local mail server .
http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/

Comment: he is using smtp he can send

Comment: @Nimesha I can send email. I have tested the script on my local machine on a testing script. The problem is that I get the above error when I try to run the same script on my original project.

Answer (score 0):

Check your include path, and also that the name of the file (LOGIN.php) matches exactly. Chances are you have a login.php instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had a __autoload in place and for some reason when the pear script is running it's trying to include a file called LOGIN which is not available. Had to include a if condition to the __autoload function as a work around. now the scipt is working but not sure whether this is the best solution. Hope its helpful for someone else having the same issue..